# how to add input validation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a multi form, i trying so many time to add input validation (If a form field (name) is empty, the required attribute prevents this form from being next button ) but more result cant run or display error....
So, I need how to add validation(name, email and password)in my multi form
For example, when click next button, need input
email validation ^[\w\d._-]+@[\w\d.-]+.[\w\d]{2,6}$
password validation ((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,15})
if no,system will display(email format is wrong)or (password format is wrong)
Here's is my script:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
          $(".form-wrapper .button").click(function(){
            var button = $(this);
            var currentSection = button.parents(".section");
            var currentSectionIndex = currentSection.index();
            var headerSection = $('.steps li').eq(currentSectionIndex);
            currentSection.removeClass("is-active").next().addClass("is-active");
            headerSection.removeClass("is-active").next().addClass("is-active");

            $(".form-wrapper").submit(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
            });

            if(currentSectionIndex === 2){
              $(document).find(".form-wrapper .section").first().addClass("is-active");
              $(document).find(".steps li").first().addClass("is-active");
            }
          });
        });
```

```css
html, body{
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
          background-color: #3498db;
        }

        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 ,h6{
          font-weight: 200;
        }

        a{
          text-decoration: none;
        }

        p, li, a{
          font-size: 14px;
        }

        fieldset{
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          border: none;
        }

        /* GRID */

        .twelve { width: 100%; }
        .eleven { width: 91.53%; }
        .ten { width: 83.06%; }
        .nine { width: 74.6%; }
        .eight { width: 66.13%; }
        .seven { width: 57.66%; }
        .six { width: 49.2%; }
        .five { width: 40.73%; }
        .four { width: 32.26%; }
        .three { width: 23.8%; }
        .two { width: 15.33%; }
        .one { width: 6.866%; }

        /* COLUMNS */

        .col {
         display: block;
         float:left;
         margin: 0 0 0 1.6%;
        }

        .col:first-of-type {
          margin-left: 0;
        }

        .container{
          width: 100%;
          max-width: 700px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          position: relative;
        }

        .row{
          padding: 20px 0;
        }

        /* CLEARFIX */

        .cf:before,
        .cf:after {
            content: " ";
            display: table;
        }

        .cf:after {
            clear: both;
        }

        .cf {
            *zoom: 1;
        }

        .wrapper{
          width: 100%;
          margin: 30px 0;
        }

        /* STEPS */

        .steps{
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          background-color: #fff;
          text-align: center;
        }


        .steps li{
          display: inline-block;
          margin: 20px;
          color: #ccc;
          padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .steps li.is-active{
          border-bottom: 1px solid #3498db;
          color: #3498db;
        }

        /* FORM */

        .form-wrapper .section{
          padding: 0px 20px 30px 20px;
          -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          background-color: #fff;
          opacity: 0;
          -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0);
          -ms-transform: scale(1, 0);
          -o-transform: scale(1, 0);
          transform: scale(1, 0);
          -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
          -moz-transform-origin: top center;
          -ms-transform-origin: top center;
          -o-transform-origin: top center;
          transform-origin: top center;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
          transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
          text-align: center;
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          min-height: 300px
        }

        .form-wrapper .section h3{
          margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        .form-wrapper .section.is-active{
          opacity: 1;
          -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
          -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
          -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
          transform: scale(1, 1);
        }

        .form-wrapper .button, .form-wrapper .submit{
          background-color: #3498db;
          display: inline-block;
          padding: 8px 30px;
          color: #fff;
          cursor: pointer;
          font-size: 14px !important;
          font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
          position: absolute;
          right: 20px;
          bottom: 20px;
        }

        .form-wrapper .submit{
          border: none;
          outline: none;
          -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
          -webkit-appearance: none;
          -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
        }

        .form-wrapper input[type="text"],
        .form-wrapper input[type="password"]{
          display: block;
          padding: 10px;
          margin: 10px auto;
          background-color: #f1f1f1;
          border: none;
          width: 50%;
          outline: none;
          font-size: 14px !important;
          font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
        }

        .form-wrapper input[type="radio"]{
          display: none;
        }

        .form-wrapper input[type="radio"] + label{
          display: block;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          width: 100%;
          max-width: 100%;
          padding: 10px;
          -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          cursor: pointer;
          position: relative;
        }

        .form-wrapper input[type="radio"] + label:before{
          content: "✔";
          position: absolute;
          right: -10px;
          top: -10px;
          width: 30px;
          height: 30px;
          line-height: 30px;
          border-radius: 100%;
          background-color: #3498db;
          color: #fff;
          display: none;
        }

        .form-wrapper input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before{
          display: block;
        }

        .form-wrapper input[type="radio"] + label h4{
          margin: 15px;
          color: #ccc;
        }

        .form-wrapper input[type="radio"]:checked + label{
          border: 1px solid #3498db;
        }

        .form-wrapper input[type="radio"]:checked + label h4{
          color: #3498db;
        }
```

```html
<html >
        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <ul class="steps">
                <li class="is-active">Step 1</li>
                <li>Step 2</li>
              </ul>
              <form class="form-wrapper">
                <fieldset class="section is-active">
                  <h3>Your Details</h3>
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                  <input class="button" type="button" value="Next">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="section">
                  <h3>Choose a Password</h3>
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                  <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Re-enter Password">
                  <input class="submit button" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="section">
                  <h3>Account Created!</h3>
                  <p>Your account has now been created.</p>
                  <div class="button">Reset Form</div>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what the problem really is. You should try to be more specific with your question. Also, please just include the relevant parts of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `required` attribute to achieve this. Pls check [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) for more validation types.

I created two separate form to check validity on each button click.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

      $(".form-wrapper .button").click(function(){
       
           var inpObj = document.getElementById("form1");
          if (inpObj.checkValidity()) {
  
        var button = $(this);
        var currentSection = button.parents(".section");
        var currentSectionIndex = currentSection.index();
        var headerSection = $('.steps li').eq(currentSectionIndex);
        currentSection.removeClass("is-active").next().addClass("is-active");
        headerSection.removeClass("is-active").next().addClass("is-active");



        $(".form-wrapper").submit(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
        });
        if(currentSectionIndex === 0){
          $(document).find("#section2").addClass("is-active");      
        }
        if(currentSectionIndex === 2){
          $(document).find("#form2 .section").addClass("is-active");
          $(document).find(".steps li").first().addClass("is-active");
        }
        }
      });
      
    });
```

```css
html, body{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      background-color: #3498db;
    }

    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 ,h6{
      font-weight: 200;
    }

    a{
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    p, li, a{
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    fieldset{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: none;
    }

    /* GRID */

    .twelve { width: 100%; }
    .eleven { width: 91.53%; }
    .ten { width: 83.06%; }
    .nine { width: 74.6%; }
    .eight { width: 66.13%; }
    .seven { width: 57.66%; }
    .six { width: 49.2%; }
    .five { width: 40.73%; }
    .four { width: 32.26%; }
    .three { width: 23.8%; }
    .two { width: 15.33%; }
    .one { width: 6.866%; }

    /* COLUMNS */

    .col {
        display: block;
        float:left;
        margin: 0 0 0 1.6%;
    }

    .col:first-of-type {
      margin-left: 0;
    }

    .container{
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 700px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
    }

    .row{
      padding: 20px 0;
    }

    /* CLEARFIX */

    .cf:before,
    .cf:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
    }

    .cf:after {
        clear: both;
    }

    .cf {
        *zoom: 1;
    }

    .wrapper{
      width: 100%;
      margin: 30px 0;
    }

    /* STEPS */

    .steps{
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
    }


    .steps li{
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 20px;
      color: #ccc;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .steps li.is-active{
      border-bottom: 1px solid #3498db;
      color: #3498db;
    }

    /* FORM */

    .form-wrapper .section{
      padding: 0px 20px 30px 20px;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color: #fff;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0);
      -ms-transform: scale(1, 0);
      -o-transform: scale(1, 0);
      transform: scale(1, 0);
      -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
      -moz-transform-origin: top center;
      -ms-transform-origin: top center;
      -o-transform-origin: top center;
      transform-origin: top center;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 300px
    }

    .form-wrapper .section h3{
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .form-wrapper .section.is-active{
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
      -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
      transform: scale(1, 1);
    }

    .form-wrapper .button, .form-wrapper .submit{
      background-color: #3498db;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 8px 30px;
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 14px !important;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
      position: absolute;
      right: 20px;
      bottom: 20px;
    }

    .form-wrapper .submit{
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
      box-sizing: content-box;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
    }

    .form-wrapper input[type="text"],
    .form-wrapper input[type="password"]{
      display: block;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px auto;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      border: none;
      width: 50%;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 14px !important;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
    }

    .form-wrapper input[type="radio"]{
      display: none;
    }

    .form-wrapper input[type="radio"] + label{
      display: block;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
    }

    .form-wrapper input[type="radio"] + label:before{
      content: "✔";
      position: absolute;
      right: -10px;
      top: -10px;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      background-color: #3498db;
      color: #fff;
      display: none;
    }

    .form-wrapper input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before{
      display: block;
    }

    .form-wrapper input[type="radio"] + label h4{
      margin: 15px;
      color: #ccc;
    }

    .form-wrapper input[type="radio"]:checked + label{
      border: 1px solid #3498db;
    }

    .form-wrapper input[type="radio"]:checked + label h4{
      color: #3498db;
    }
```

```html
<html >
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script>
   
    </script>
    <style>
   
    </style>  
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <ul class="steps">
            <li class="is-active">Step 1</li>
            <li>Step 2</li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-wrapper"  id="form1">
            <fieldset class="section is-active">
              <h3>Your Details</h3>
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
              <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
              
               <button class="button">Next</button>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
              <form class="form-wrapper" id="form2">
            <fieldset class="section" id="section2">
              <h3>Choose a Password</h3>
              <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
              <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Re-enter Password">
              <input class="submit button" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="section" id="section3">
              <h3>Account Created!</h3>
              <p>Your account has now been created.</p>
              <div class="button">Reset Form</div>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I already try, but when i click next button step 1 to step 2 , step 2 cannot display form..

Comment: I just updated one form to show.. I updated my answer to move between them as well

Comment: Thank you, could u know how to add function or validation for email ^[\w\d._-]+@[\w\d.-]+.[\w\d]{2,6}$ and password ((?=.\d)(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])(?=.[@#$%]).{8,15})?

Comment: when you click reset button ,you will back to page 2 only

Answer (score 0):

Use required attribute in input tag to make the field mandatory

```
 <form class="form-wrapper">
            <fieldset class="section is-active">
              <h3>Your Details</h3>
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
              <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
              <input class="button" type="button" value="Next">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="section">
              <h3>Choose a Password</h3>
              <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
              <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Re-enter Password" required>
              <input class="submit button" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="section">
              <h3>Account Created!</h3>
              <p>Your account has now been created.</p>
              <div class="button">Reset Form</div>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
```